# MvvmCross First Demo not running on Xamarin Studio

Tags: mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to run the MvvmCross Tutorials on Xamarin Studio, but I'm having no luck.

`https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-00-FirstDemo`

Currently I want to run the FirstDemo.Touch but it is not even building. The Core is building, the FirstDemo.Droid is building and running on a Virtual Device.

But the .Touch project is grayed out, with a "not built in active configuration" message. When I try to build it, I get an error saying "No valid iPhone code signing keys found in keychain". I just want to build it and run it on an emulator.

Oh, I downloaded the Tasky demo (from Xamarin) and it builds and runs ok on the iOS emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Touch is for iOS devices.

You would have to select that build configuration (Debug - iPhone Simulator) to not gray it out. Make sure you dont have iOS Device selected because you need an actual developer account and provisioning profiles to deploy to an actual device.

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed that. What a dumb of me.

Comment: By the way, you can set it on the drop-down box aside the "Play/Hammer" button on top bar, or by the menu "Project/Active Configuration".